How does image render in column in Jetpack Compose
I am doing one practice assignment where I have to build a screen for the app. Screen should look like -

I am able to render text segment as per the assignment but while rendering Image, Image is filling full width of screen.
My code is -
    @Composable
fun JetpackComposeTutorial() {
    Column {
    Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.bg_compose_background),
        contentDescription = null,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(100.dp)
        )

        Text(
            text = stringResource(R.string.jetpack_compose_tutorial),
            fontSize = 24.sp,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
        )
        Text(
            text = stringResource(R.string.jetpack_compose_abstract),
            fontSize = 14.sp,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp),
            textAlign = TextAlign.Justify
        )
        Text(
            text = stringResource(R.string.jetpack_compose_des),
            fontSize = 14.sp,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Justify
        )
    }
}

and output is -

Is the modifier causing the problem because below given code rendering my screen as per the expectation?
@Composable
fun JetpackComposeTutorial() {
    Column {
    Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.bg_compose_background),
        contentDescription = null,
        //modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(120.dp)
        )

        Text(
            text = stringResource(R.string.jetpack_compose_tutorial),
            fontSize = 24.sp,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
        )
        Text(
            text = stringResource(R.string.jetpack_compose_abstract),
            fontSize = 14.sp,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp),
            textAlign = TextAlign.Justify
        )
        Text(
            text = stringResource(R.string.jetpack_compose_des),
            fontSize = 14.sp,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Justify
        )
    }
}


Have a look at the specifications of the Image Composable:
@Composable
fun Image(
    painter: Painter,
    contentDescription: String?,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    alignment: Alignment = Alignment.Center,
    contentScale: ContentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
    alpha: Float = DefaultAlpha,
    colorFilter: ColorFilter? = null
): Unit

The Image Composable will use ContentScale.Fit by default, meaning that it will be placed in the available space while maintaining the aspect ratio.
You are both specifying the width and height of your Image Compoable. I suspect that the height you define is too small to make the Image fit. So please try to only specify width and let the height be picked automatically like this:
Image(
    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.bg_compose_background),
    contentDescription = null,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
)

Otherwise, you can play around with the contentScale attribute to make the Image scale or crop.
